# Top alignment of dynamic collection view cells should be same

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

[image]We are displaying a collection view with two cells in a row and displaying the label (dynamic with text) in each collectionviewcell.

We are able to achieve this by

```
override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
```

The two cells in a row data are aligned as centered. can we make this to top-aligned?

Example: 
Assume there are two cells with 2 lines of text in one cell and 4 lines of text in 2nd cell.
In this case, these two labels are centering aligned with each other. Can we make them top aligned?

Thanks in advance,
Ram

Comment: Can you just provide a screenshot ?

Comment: Updated @jtouzy. Can you please have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used `AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout` for the quick solution.

https://github.com/mischa-hildebrand/AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout

Answer (score 0):

I have aprx same functionality so I am sharing what I have done in working condition. If your requirement is slightly different then you need to do more customization.

For code explanation, I suggest you to go through references links mentioned in last section of answer.

---

**Create Custom FlowLayout Class**

```
class CustomLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    private var computedContentSize: CGSize = .zero
    private var cellAttributes = [IndexPath: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
     var array = [String]()

    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return computedContentSize
    }

    override func prepare() {
        computedContentSize = .zero
        cellAttributes = [IndexPath: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        var preY = 10
        var highY = 10

        for section in 0 ..< collectionView!.numberOfSections {
            var i = 0
            for item in 0 ..< collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: section) {
                let awidth =  Int((self.collectionView?.bounds.width)!) / 3 - 15
                let aheight = self.array[item].height(withConstrainedWidth: CGFloat(awidth), font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)) + 20

                var aX = 10

                if item % 3 == 1 {
                    aX = aX + 10 + awidth
                }
                else if item % 3 == 2 {
                    aX = aX + 20 + 2 * awidth
                }
                else {
                    aX = 10
                    preY = highY
                }

                if highY < preY + Int(aheight) {
                    highY = preY + Int(aheight) + 5
                }

                let itemFrame = CGRect(x: aX, y: preY, width: awidth, height: Int(aheight))
                let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
                let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
                attributes.frame = itemFrame

                cellAttributes[indexPath] = attributes
                i += 1
            }
        }

        computedContentSize = CGSize(width: (self.collectionView?.bounds.width)!,
                                     height: CGFloat(collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) * 70))
    }


    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        var attributeList = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        for (_, attributes) in cellAttributes {
            if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
                attributeList.append(attributes)
            }
        }

        return attributeList
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return cellAttributes[indexPath]
    }
}
```

**MainViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    @IBOutlet weak var myColView: UICollectionView!

    var array = ["Hello", "Look Behind", "Gotta get there", "Hey buddy", "Earth is rotating around the sun", "Sky is blue", "Kill yourself", "Humble docters", "Lets make party tonight Lets make party tonight", "Lets play PUB-G", "Where are you?", "Love you Iron Man."]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let myLayout =  CustomLayout()
        myLayout.array = self.array
        myColView.collectionViewLayout = myLayout
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
        cell.myLabel.text = array[indexPath.row]
        cell.myLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        cell.myLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1

        return cell

    }
}
```

**Used extensions**

```
extension String {
    func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], context: nil)

        return ceil(boundingBox.height)
    }

    func width(withConstrainedHeight height: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], context: nil)

        return ceil(boundingBox.width)
    }
}
```

### Output:

> [image]

### Reference:

- https://www.raywenderlich.com/4829472-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest
- https://www.netguru.com/codestories/practical-introduction-to-custom-uicollectionview-layouts
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/customizing_collection_view_layouts